# Can't create rails test db

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I see lots of questions, about this, and I have tried everything:

Here is my database.yml file:

```
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: myname
  password: mypassword
  database: project-test
  encoding: utf8
```

I have gone into mysql and here is the password table:

```
mysql> use mysql
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> update user set password = PASSWORD('mypassword') where user = 'myname' and host = 'localhost';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
mysql> select Host, User, Password from user;
 +-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
 | Host      | User     | Password                                  |
 +-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
 | localhost | root     |                                           |
 | rmv.local | root     |                                           |
 | 127.0.0.1 | root     |                                           |
 | localhost |          |                                           |
 | rmv.local |          |                                           |
 | localhost | myname   | *D5CE3D8B65EF4DF67D9E8FD30184C66EF9DDEF29 |
 +-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
```

but no matter what I get:

```
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'myname'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to GRANT CREATE privileges to the user! That was it!